# Construction permettant l'omission de « de »

Tags: grammaire, négation, articles, constructions

Comment appelle-t-on la construction qui permet l'omission de *de* dans cet exemple?

« Je n'ai jamais rencontré soldat aussi discret. »

La forme négative et l'utilisation de *aussi* ou *si* (voire *si peu*) en sont les signes distinctifs.

Comment: T'es sûr que c'est pas *un* qui est omis ? :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez ça me semble bancal: je pense que ça vient du fait que *de* peut être omis au singulier comme au pluriel (et pas un) donc il me vient plus naturellement. *de* véhicule le sens de *parmi les autres* qui est absent lorsqu'on utilise (pas) *un*. Après tout peu importe le mot qu'on omet: ce pourrait tout aussi bien être *sulfateuse*.

Comment: _Je n'ai jamais rencontré sulfateuse soldat aussi discret_ ? Hein?

Comment: @Stéphane Je n'ai jamais lu _de_ commentaire aussi erroné. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Il s'avère](http://books.google.fr/books?id=lskaSr4WCFQC&pg=PA47&dq=%22jamais%22) qu'il existe des tournures introduites par un adverbe quantifieur négatif ou restrictif qui permettent des constructions à article zéro.

« Rarement soldat fut plus froussard. »

Answer (score 5):

*De* est ici article partitif (et d'ailleurs on pourrait tout aussi bien employer l'article indéfini dans l'exemple que tu cites, comme le fait remarquer Stéphane Gimenez).
En français la règle générale est de mettre un article devant le substantif sauf cas particuliers ou effet de style recherché. Le terme grammatical pour parler de l'absence d'article est *article zéro* ou *Ø*. C'est un terme grammatical et pas une figure de style.

Comment: +1 tu m'as mis sur la voie (ou plutot la *voix* passive): « Jamais soldat aussi discret n'a été rencontré (par moi). »

Answer (score 1):

Les figures d'omission sont souvent des "ellipses".

Comment: Hmm, merci pour ta participation, mais tu n'as rien de plus précis ? « Les figures » en général, « souvent ». Merci néanmoins pour la piste !

Comment: les figures de style qui correspondent à une omission est généralement une ellipse. Je pense qu'ici c'est le cas. De même, Eugène Delacroix a fait une ellipse en écrivant "_Je n'avance guère. Le temps beaucoup_" (ellipse pour "le temps _avance_ beaucoup"

Comment: Il existe de nombreux exemples pour illustrer "l'ellipse".La définition rapporte "Omettre des éléments syntaxiques sans altérer la signification sémantique".On présente souvent les ellipses pour raccourcir une description, laissant le soin au lecteur de réaliser mentalement une répétition ***_Avec le sable, le vent, l'odeur de l'iode..._*** Un exemple un peu plus élaboré, à faire douter de sa validité syntaxique. André Gide : ***_Cette merveille qu’est ton corps, cette plus étonnante encore, ton esprit._***